# DropDownList can't see the control in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two drop downs, dependant on the end users area of business I'm wanting to disable one and hide it.

The ddls are in a gridview & I'm getting 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' & the ddl being null, I tested this outside of a gridview and it worked fine.

aspx

```
                    

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="RowID, Status,Code"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Names="Calibri" PageSize="10" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="Code" HeaderText="Client Code" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Client" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status Tracker" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClientStatus" Name="ddlClientStatus" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  onselectedindexchanged="StatusSelected"  >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val1">1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val2">2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val3">3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val4">4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val5">5</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="150px"/>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClientStatusPL" Name="ddlClientStatusPL" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  onselectedindexchanged="StatusSelected"  >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val6">6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val7">7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val8">8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val9">9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Val10">10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="150px"/>

            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

cs

```
namespace Dashboard
{

    public partial class StatusTracker : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              role = Request.QueryString["role"];

            if (role == "Sales")
            {
                ddlClientStatus.Enabled = false;
                ddlClientStatus.Visible = false;
                ddlClientStatusPL.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlClientStatus.Enabled = true;
                ddlClientStatusPL.Enabled = false;
                ddlClientStatusPL.Visible = false;
            }


        } 
   }
}
```

I've also tried the below with no joy, still a null for the ddls.

```
DropDownList ddlClientStatus = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("ddlClientStatus");
DropDownList ddlClientStatusPL = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("ddlClientStatusPL");
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.... Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: `ddlClientStatus` is inside each item of the GridView. That means inside each Row of the GridView. You can not get it by `GridView1.FindControl`. You need to iterate thru the GridView Rows and find the dropdownlist in each row.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/53559/accessing-a-dropdownlist-inside-a-gridview

Comment: public void GV1_ddl()
        {

            foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                ddlClientStatus.Enabled = false;
            }

        } Like this you mean?

Comment: Please try to follow the code patterns in the link I shared.

Comment: But that is based on a selection being made on the ddl which seems to differ to what I'm trying to achieve, unless I'm missing the point (sorry if so).

Comment: What you are trying to achieve! Can you please elaborate in the question? It not clear why you have ddl in the grid view

Comment: Dependant on a string value (passed parameter) disable/hide one ddl leaving the other available. So the end user wouldn't be aware that one had been hidden.

Comment: Also going back to your initial post you said each row would have to be looped through, would that be the case if the ddl control was being disabled on page load? It doesn't strike me as it would be the case.

Comment: Yes.. you have to loop thru the GridView Rows, Get the ddl using row.FindControl and enable/disable it... DDLs which are part of ItemTemplate, they are not directly accessible. Please read thru the link I shared and try to understand how things work from the code in it.

Comment: Ask yourself a question, if the gridview had 4 rows it will show 4 drowndown lists and if you want to disable 2nd row dropdown how do you find that dropdown? If you do `GridView1.FindControl("ddlClientStatus")` which, out of 4, dropdown it will return?

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying but that's not what I'm trying to do, the ddl will be disabled on page load, it's not specific to (your example) the 2nd row.

Comment: which ddl will be disabled on the page_load? Is that ddl inside gridView row? How many rows you have in the gridView?

Comment: If you look in the cs i posted you can see what I'm attempting to do, if the role is sales then disable one of the ddls, else disable the one that sales had enabled. So yes they are part of the gridview but my thinking was being able to dictate which would be used on page load. My other thinking was that maybe applying the values for the drop down in cs instead of the aspx? the amount of rows vary, can be four could be 500.

Comment: `if the role is sales then disable one of the ddls` which one of the four or 500? How do you plan to get that one ddl? The approach you have used is certainly not working and the approach which I am suggesting and works well you are not ready to even try. What else I can suggest?

Comment: I don't believe I can achieve what I want, the approach you've suggested is reliant on SelectedIndexChanged which also isn't going to give me what I want at all.

Comment: You can loop thru the GridView.Rows collection in any part of the code behind. The example give in the link is for SelectionindexChanged. All you need to understand is how to access the DropDownList from the GridView if it is part of ItemTemplate. So instead of just denying the fact, please try to read it thru and understand what is happening there.. if you have a dropdownlist in the ItemTemplate, you can access it only via GridViewRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating your drop down lists inside of a gridview, you need to wait until the gridview has rows populated.

When this happens, you can hook into gridview's RowDatabound event to set the visible and/or display properties of your dropdown lists.

`<asp:GridView ID="dataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) handles
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlClientStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlClientStatus");
        DropDownList ddlClientStatusPL =(DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlClientStatusPL");
        
        ddlClientStatus.Visible =  //do your logic to determine which should be visible / enabled
        ddlClientStatusPL.Visible = !ddlClientStatus.visible
     }
}
```

Comment: ClearlyClueless..... That's exactly what I was missing! Another notch in my belt for GridView knowledge, thank you for a superb explanation and example!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to solve your problem by replicating similar scenario. In this case, there is a GridView in the page which shows data of some persons. Each person have firstname, lastname and role.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

}
```

Following is the code from .aspx.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Admin" Text="Admin"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="SuperAdmin" Text="Super Admin"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lead" Text="Lead" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Developer" Text="Developer" ></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see the grid view has two BoundFields and on TemplateField and the TemplateFields has a dropdownlist in it. The dropdownlist has 4 items added to it.

Following is the code in code behind which load persons data in the GridView.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateGridView();
        }
    }
    private void PopulateGridView()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();

        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Blithe", LastName = "Taig", Role = "Developer" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Ewan", LastName = "Critoph", Role = "SuperAdmin" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Hyatt", LastName = "Atkinson", Role = "Lead" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Paloma", LastName = "Bauldry", Role = "Lead" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Eldon", LastName = "Lambert", Role = "Developer" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Ethyl", LastName = "Mugford", Role = "Lead" });
        persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Leupold", LastName = "Longmuir", Role = "SuperAdmin" });

        dataGridView.DataSource = persons;
        dataGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

With the above code, the Gridview is populated as following.

[image]

You can see that all the persons have role `Admin` selected in the gridview while they have different value set for Role in the code above. the dropdown list in the GridView Items do not get the values from the GridView DataSource by default. The values of DDL in each row need to be set by code.

For this I used `RowDataBound` event of the GridView. First I added `OnRowDataBound="dataGridView_RowDataBound"` attirbute in GridView inside aspx.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="dataGridView_RowDataBound" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
```

And also created this event handler in the aspx.cs.

```
protected void dataGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataItem = e.Row.DataItem as Person;

        if(dataItem != null)
        {
            var ddlRoles = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlRoles");
            if(ddlRoles != null)
            {
                ddlRoles.SelectedValue = dataItem.Role;
            }
        }
    }
```

With this change, the Role column in the GridView has now proper role selected in each row.

[image]

You can see in the code of `dataGridView_RowDataBound` how dropDown list is retrieved from the Row of Gridview by doing `(DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlRoles")`.

Now coming to the similar feature you are implementing. There will be a query string parameter name `role`. And the gridview should have all the dropdownlist disabled which has that role selected.

Following is the code I wrote for disabling the dropdown.

```
private void DisableRole(string role)
    {
        // Loop thru GridView Rows.
        foreach(GridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            // Try to find dropdownlist with id=ddlRoles from each row.
            var ddlRole = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlRoles");
            // Disabled the dropdownlist if it is found the it has matching role selected
            if(ddlRole != null && ddlRole.SelectedItem.Value == role)
            {
                ddlRole.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then called this method from `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateGridView();
        }

        var role = Request.QueryString["role"];

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
        {
            DisableRole(role);
        }
    }
```

With this change, when I browse URL http://localhost:53384/Default?role=Lead, the dropdowns with Lead selected in them are disabled.

[image]

In the code above I am iterating thru the Rows collection of GridView and finding Dropdownlist inside each row and trying to disable them.

The scenario I explained might be little different than yours. What I am trying to demonstrate is, if you need to access any control which is placed inside ItemTemplate of a GridView, you can only access it via GridViewRow. And you can loop thru the GridView.Rows collection wherever you need to.

I hope this will resole your doubts and help you resolve your issue.